# iOS - Custom UISwitch in UITableViewCell dealloc error

Tags: ios, objective-c, dealloc

I am using a UISwitch subclass to add UISwitches to all my UITableViewCells. I use the custom class to be able to pass more info to the UISwitch.

The error I have on iOS 8 ONLY is:

```
*** -[NamedUISwitch _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

NamedUISwitch is the Custom UISwitch I made:

```
@interface NamedUISwitch : UISwitch
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *specialinfo1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *specialinfo2;
@end

@implementation NamedUISwitch

@end
```

This is how I implement my UISwitch in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
    NamedUISwitch *switchview = [[NamedUISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [switchview addTarget:self action:@selector(updateSwitchAtIndexPath:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.textLabel.text = ...;
    switchview.nomEtablissement = ...;
    switchview.tag = ...;
    switchview.typeInfo = ...;
    cell.accessoryView = switchview;
    return cell;
}
```

I have tried using Instruments to track the dealloc but I can't seem to get it to work the right way.
How can I resolve this dealloc issue?

Comment: Update your question with your complete `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: This is exactly how I do it. I've put "..." instead of the tables I get the data from, but that's not the issue. So there you go!

Comment: Why aren't you creating your cells properly? Please see the [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451) for details.

Comment: OP, you need to dequeue your TV cells, and init if they're nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not creating your cells correctly. You need code something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    NamedUISwitch *switchview = nil;
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
        switchview = [[NamedUISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [switchview addTarget:self action:@selector(updateSwitchAtIndexPath:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.accessoryView = switchview;
    } else {
        switchview = cell.accessoryview;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = ...;
    switchview.nomEtablissement = ...;
    switchview.tag = ...;
    switchview.typeInfo = ...;
    // You also need to set switchview.on here

    return cell;
}
```

This way you reuse cells properly and each cell only gets one switch.

An even better option would be to create a custom table cell class and that cell class sets up its own switch.

Comment: This is beautiful. Don't know how I missed that. Great answer thanks alot.

Comment: In case anyone has an issue with UISwitches being either on/hidden because of the reuse, simply add switchview.on = NO and switchview.hidden = NO in the else{} part.

Comment: @user3209448 No, not in the `else` part. After the whole `if/else` part. You need to set the `on` value (or any other cell or switch properties) in both cases.